# How to implement go-to javascript links? (plus highlight)

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, anchor

Is there a standard way for making all the links in a site, with the form href=#something, become 'go-to' links? (does this kind of links have a name?)

Let me describe these links further: When you click them, #something is added to the url. And if you go directly to that url from your browser, it takes you to that page, and then it scrolls down to that link.

Take this link as example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe#cite_note-Craig-45

Edit: As you can see, the div gets highlighted. How to make that happen automatically?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Does my answer below clear things up?

Comment: In the future, try to be a bit more specific early on (so people don't end up writing answers that don't address your revised question at all).

Comment: @Tim Post How can I be specific about something that I don't even know in which language is done? I still can't find the code that is used for the link posted, and no one has said anything on that subject so far.

Answer (score 3):

You're referring to anchor tags. Here's an example of a JavaScript-less internal link:

```
<a href="#myDiv">Go to my div!</a>

<div id="myDiv">
    This is content
</div>
```

If you want to send someone to `myDiv` using JavaScript, then you could do it this way:

```
<span onclick="window.location.hash = '#myDiv'">Go to my div!</span>

<div id="myDiv">
    This is content
</div>
```

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjYvv/) that demonstrates both the HTML and JavaScript methods.

You can also use a similar method to allow the use to navigate to page and then scroll them to the appropriate element on the page. Simply add the hash (#) plus the ID of the element to the URL. For example:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/mypage.com/#myDiv">Go to my page and then div!</a>
```

Or, with JavaScript

```
<a href="javascript: window.location.href = 'http://www.mysite.com/mypage.com/#myDiv'">Go to my page and then div!</a>
```

Comment: I think this is the closest answer to what I want. But I need it to be able to also do this: I copy-paste the full url including the hash into a new tab I open in my browser, the page loads, and then scrolls down automatically, because of the hash in the url (as in the wikipedia example in the OP)

Comment: I must have been doing something wrong, now I see that js isn't necessary. One last question: How can I execute some js code after going to that url? I want to highlight the div, or execute js code that is binded to that div (like opening a modal window).

Comment: @HappyDeveloper, that answer is beyond the scope of this question. I suggest asking a new question.

Comment: It's pretty related if you ask me. I want to do exactly what the link posted does: go to a div and highlight it

Comment: @HappyDeveloper, Respectfully, until you just edited your question, a day after you asked it, it mentioned nothing about highlighting the element. How can my answer go from one you accepted as correct, to being incorrect? Posting your (new) highlighting question as a new question benefits everyone, including you. For example, had you posted it in a new question instead of editing your existing question, you would probably have a plethora of answers to choose from by now.

Comment: Because I thought the answer was going to include how to trigger not only the highlight, but any js code I wanted (from the question you can tell that I thought the go-to thing was a javascript thing). I just want to do exactly what the link posted does (and I posted it the first time, not in the edit). Answering that was probably just 1 extra LoC, but instead of answering you told me to write another question (gives the impression that as long as you get your answer accepted, you don't care anymore about my problem), which is annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `id` attribute of the `a` tag. Place the following at the location you would like to link to:

`<a id="example"></a>`

You can then link to that using:

`<a href="#example">Go to example</a>`

If you want to link to a specific anchor on a different page, simply use the `#` character after the URL:

`<a href="somewhere.html#example">Go to different page example</a>`

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/xgKT8/).

Comment: -1 because `name` will be obsolete in HTML 5. Additionaly `name` can be used only on some elements whereas `id` can be used on all elements.

Comment: @Saxoier - Nice point. I very rarely use anchors like this so I'm rusty! I should probably remember from the fact that `#` specifies an ID selector in CSS...

Answer (score 0):

The thing after the # is called an anchor, and is defined using the a-tag: `<a id="something">`.

If you just have #something as a link, like `<a href="#something">`, it will resolve relatively to the current page. So if your page is at http://myurl/mypage.html then it will open http://myurl/mypage.html#something.